# Optimized way to toggle multiple divs with the same handling function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a page in my react project, in which there are 4 divs(for dropdown) with different classnames and toggled each div to toggle options for each dropdown. 
But for that, I have used 4 flag state variables and created 4 handling functions to toggle options for dropdowns.

Showing code for 2 divs:

```
class CustomTimeView extends Component {
    state = {
        showFirst: false,
        showSecond: false
    };
    handleFirst = (event) => {
        const {showFirst} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            showFirst: !showFirst
        });
    }
    handleSecond = (event) => {
        const {showSecond} = this.state;
        this.setState({
           showSecond: !showSecond
        });
    }
    render() {
        const {showFirst, showSecond} = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
            <div className="first-dropdown" onClick={this.handleFirst}>
                 First value
            </div>
            {showFirst &&
                <div className="first-option">Option One</div>
            }
            <div className="first-dropdown" onClick={this.handleFirst}>
                 Second label
            </div>
            {showSecond &&
                <div className="first-option">Option Two</div>
            }
        </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem with a single handling function. I don't want to use redux for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try `onClick={()=> this.handle(index)}`

Answer (score 1):

You could separate things like this. You can re-use the Toggle component and pass the proper handle function.

You could also put this all in one file. Depends on what you will do with your toggles.

```
const Toggle = ({ id, children, handleToggle }) => (
  <div className={`${id}-dropdown`} onClick={() => handleToggle(id)}>
   {children}
  </div>
);

class App {
  state = { first: false, second: false };

  handle = id => this.setState({ [id]: !this.state[id] });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle id="first" handleToggle={this.handle}>
          First Value
        </Toggle>
        <Toggle id="second" handleToggle={this.handle}>
          Second Value
        </Toggle>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lokuzt, it woks fine by creating a separate Toggle component.